# R-metafor. Subgroup analysis in meta-analysis: Is it possible to compute bootstrapped CI in {metafor} model function

Tags: r, bootstrap, meta-analysis

As many meta-analysts, I am running a subgroup analysis:

`res<-rma.uni(yi,vi, mods = ~ factor(Plant.type), method = "ML", data=dat)`

where I have bootrapped the confidence intervals for both subgroups:

```
boot.group1 <- function(dat.group1, indices) {
res.group1 <- try(rma(yi, vi, data=dat, subset=indices), silent=TRUE)
if (is.element("try-error", class(ROM.YI))) {
NA
} else {
c(coef(res.group1), vcov(res.group1))
}
}
boot.group1 <- boot(dat, boot.group1, R=10000)
boot.ci(boot.group1, index=1:2) # same thing for group2
```

However, since my new bootstrapped confidence intervals differ from the previous ones yielded by metafor (my bootstrapped CI are narrower), so will do the degree of significance between these 2 groups and the amount of heterogeneity explained by this moderator (Test of Moderators).

So my question is: **Is there a way to compute the bootstrapped confidence intervals/variance in this model so I can obtain the results in line?**

Comment: I think the issue here is explained in the package author's pages http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:comp_two_independent_estimates but not in the context of bootstrapping. Perhaps you can have a look and then maybe clarify your question if I have mis-understood?

Comment: Right, I can just replace "sei" in this formula with my bootstrapped standard errors: rma(estimate, sei=stderror, mods = ~ meta, method="FE", data=dat.comp, digits=3). Many thanks mdewey